# Trying to connect to an API and opened MySQL port so it would work, but terminal just hangs

Tags: python, django, networking, zoho

I'm trying to connect to the `zcrmsdk` python API by Zoho CRM.

At first when I would try to connect the API would tell me that the MySQL database refused connection and couldn't connect on port 3306. Here's the error:

```
  File "/Users/hgducharme/Programming/Environments/SentriForceEnvironment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (61 Connection refused)
```

So next I opened up port 3306 on my localhost by running `nc -l localhost 3306`.

Now when I send the command to connect to the API, my terminal just hangs.

Here is my python code to connect with the API:

```
from zcrmsdk import ZCRMRestClient, ZohoOAuth

# Tell Zoho it's me
config = {
    'sandbox': 'False',
    'applicationLogFilePath': './log',
    'client_id': '1000.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    'client_secret': 'e9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8000/some_path',
    'accounts_url': 'https://accounts.zoho.com',
    'token_persistance_path': '.',
    'currentUserEmail': 'email@gmail.com'
}

# Get an access token
ZCRMRestClient.initialize(config)
oauthClient = ZohoOAuth.get_client_instance()
grantToken = "1000.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
oauthTokens = oauthClient.generate_access_token(grantToken)
```

Comment: What did you expect when it’s trying to connect to a server and there isn’t a server, instead just netcat not sending anything to the waiting process?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Honestly i'm not sure. I'm pretty new to this and i'm trying to figure out what is going on

Comment: In any case what is the question here? You haven’t asked anything so nothing can be answered. But if the system needs a MySQL database then it needs it and you can’t just skip it.

Comment: The question is how do I fix this? I have no idea what the fix is, but no the system doesn't require a MySQL database to be established. Here is the exact tutorial I was following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=660sm_1HPG0. Their documentation is rather poor and I can't really figure out where to go from here. Notice in the video he doesn't mention anything about ports or setting up a database. I followed his exact steps and when i went to do it I ran into the following errors above

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen any suggestions?